# "This is the 23rd question asked by an old user"

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, first-post-review

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59244098/is-react-event-driven) in the *First posts* queue:

> [image: question screenshot]

I noticed that the user had more than 500 reputation, so I'd checked [the user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10228119/amas) and I saw the user had already asked 22 questions before. And this was their 23<sup>rd</sup> question.

Because my current reputation is lower than 10k, I couldn't view the deleted question to check that it's an audit or not.

If the question was real, the explanation on the top is *wrong*:

> The is the **first question** asked by a new user...

If it's just a audit, that's fine but... do you think there is some *new user* who has a gold badge?

It may be the *first question*, but since they have more than 500 reputation, they cannot be a *new user*.

Can you please explain to me why it's in the queue?

Comment: It's an audit ('test'), for sure! I hope you didn't click "No Action Needed!" If you had clicked on "link" you would have seen that the post was deleted and, thus, was an audit.

Comment: @AdrianMole Nope. My experience said that *a deleted question still needs an action* (to be deleted). But the real question can be deleted, too. Maybe he had aready answered a lot of questions to get more than 500 reputation and this is the first question.... Something like that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question is in the queue only as an audit. Since it was heavily downvoted, closed, and deleted by community members; it was chosen as a "known bad" post. The only way you will find a deleted post on a review queue is as a review audit.

Audits are just testing that you are paying attention and do not need to conform to the regular rules of the queue. E.g. to be a user's first post, in this case.

On audits, some post data may be altered, but some details will not. That you caught up with these inconsistencies means that you were paying attention, which is great.

Comment: Thanks! I see you mention about *known bad post*. I just wonder why is it in *Low quality post* queue instead? If it's in there, I can recommend to delete it. But if it's in *First post* queue, a lot of controls are disabled, such as: voting, closing, flagging, editing, sharing (although no one wants to share a bad question)

Comment: Neither voting (up/down or close), flagging or editing are disabled in the first posts queue.

Comment: A closed question can be edited while a deleted question cannot. I don't think that moving a deleted question to *Close votes* queue is a good idea (by voting to close it here).

Comment: @Tân It's an audit, if you vote to close you are just confirming previous user's actions, the close vote would not be recorded as such.

Comment: But if it's an audit, that's ok. Nothing will be *moved*. But if it's a real question.....mm.... I mean...nope, it should be another question. Thanks!

Comment: No deleted post would be presented to you on review unless it's an audit.

Comment: Yes. `No deleted post would be presented` but there is still some presentation post to be deleted (the post is deleted while I'm reading).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean and how is related to your question here.

Comment: You solve my question on commenting: `It's an audit` and `No deleted post would be presented to you on review unless it's an audit`. I just provide another case to view some deleted post and the post is not an audit. Totally, thank you!

Comment: @Tân It's an audit! If you had voted to close or flagged (any reason, I think), you would have been suitably congratulated by the Audit Master-Bot, and shown a 'view' of the actual (deleted) question. If you had tried to add a comment, you would have seen the peculiar "This is an audit" pop-up when you tried typing your comment text.